# Running of the block with creation of AttentionSeq2Seq in google/seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow, sequence-to-sequence

Recently Google had released new implementation for seq2seq algorithm: https://github.com/google/seq2seq/blob/master/docs/nmt.md. They had changed the entire internal structure of the code. I tried to modify the code for mine purposes (I created new InputPipeline decoder). When I run the code without any modifications, it works fine: all tasks called and training launches without any problem. After experiment creation started, tensorflow displays the messages about creation of all of the hooks:

```
...
INFO:tensorflow:Creating ParallelTextInputPipeline in mode=train
...
INFO:tensorflow:Creating ParallelTextInputPipeline in mode=eval
...
INFO:tensorflow:Creating PrintModelAnalysisHook in mode=train
...
INFO:tensorflow:Creating RougeMetricSpec in mode=eval
...
```

This part works fine. But after that, the original code calls the creation of an AttentionSeq2Seq, vocabulary lookup tables, BidirectionalRNNEncoder, AttentionLayerDot, AttentionDecoder, ZeroBridge tasks in train mode:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Creating AttentionSeq2Seq in mode=train
...
INFO:tensorflow:Creating vocabulary lookup table of size 34
INFO:tensorflow:Creating vocabulary lookup table of size 46
INFO:tensorflow:Creating BidirectionalRNNEncoder in mode=train
...
```

And this part with creation of the AttentionSeq2Seq, vocabulary lookup tables, etc. tasks doesn't launch after my modifications.
Could you explain me, how these tasks launches in the original version?